# How to use dll's in the same directory as an excel file

Tags: windows, excel, dll

This is somewhat related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970404/trouble-with-file-location-in-excel-fortran-dll-connection).

I've been using a dll to acompany an excel spreadsheet. Everything is currently working with the dll and excel is using it just fine. But is it possible to specify that a dll resides in the same directory as the excel file when declaring functions?

```
Declare Sub FortranCall Lib "Fcall.dll" (r1 As Long, ByVal num As String)
```

Unfortunetly this doesn't work, I have to use something like:

```
Declare Sub FortranCall Lib "C:\temp\Fcall.dll" (r1 As Long, ByVal num As String)
```

This works, but is going to cause headaches when distributing to my office mates. Placing the dll in c:\windows\system32 etc. is not really an option either.

Comment: Hi, so what did you finally go with ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are [three possibilities](http://blogs.msdn.com/pranavwagh/archive/2006/08/30/How-To-Load-Win32-dlls-Dynamically-In-VBA.aspx) for dynamically loading/calling into DLLs from VBA, including links to relevant info and some sample code.  Can't say I've ever had to use any of the solutions described there, but it seems like a reasonable exploration of the options in light of VBA's need for a static path.

1. Create a new module at runtime (you could import a .bas file from disk, no need to hard-code the module with string literals), using the VBIDE Extensibility API. Drawback: no compile-time validation; you'll need to use stringly-typed `Application.Run` calls to invoke it. Requires trusted programmatic access to the VBIDE API (i.e. you allow VBA to execute code that generates code that is then executed... like macro viruses do).
2. Use the `LoadLibrary` Win32 API... and now you've got pointers and addresses: [this scary code](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1863) (.zip download) is essentially a huge unmaintainable hack that uses assembly language to enable invoking the API functions by name. Looks like it only works for a subset of supported Win32 API functions though.
3. Change the DLL search path, but then that *also* requires dynamic code added at run-time, so might as well go with the above.

Here's [another potential solution](http://communities.bentley.com/forums/permalink/23802/23917/ShowThread.aspx#23917) that suggests programmatically updating the PATH environment variable prior to calling into your DLL.  Not a bad idea, if it works, as you could add this to you workbook open event.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately the link regarding updating the PATH is dead

Comment: Re the dead second link above, it looks like they reorganized at some point and didn't provide redirects.  I can't be sure this is the same post, but it seems on topic (see the comments for details):
https://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/f/microstation-forum/12979/where-to-place-dll-s-to-be-called-from-vba

Answer (score 3):

The way I generally take care of this is by adding:

```
Dim CurrentPath As String
CurrentPath = CurDir()   
ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)
```

To: Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Answer (score 2):

ChDir() should do the trick. It might not work on network folders though.

```
Declare Sub FortranCall Lib "Fcall.dll" (r1 As Long, ByVal num As String)
...
Dim CurrentPath As String
CurrentPath = CurDir()   
ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)
Call FortranCall(r, n)
ChDir (CurrentPath) ' Change back to original directory
```

Now keep your .dll in the same folder as your workbook.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the DLL in some directory and add it to the path EnVar.

Comment: Please, could you explain a little more what did you mean. Did you mean I add the DLL into the PATH enviromental variable ? I'm afraid that will not be a satisfactory solution - it would be easier in that case to just ask them to keep the excel and dll file in a predefined directory scructure. I'm trying to accomplish as much as "portable" solution as possible.

Answer (score -2):

`ActiveWorkbook.Path` gives you the full path to the folder containing the currently-active workbook.  So try this:

```
Declare Sub FortranCall Lib ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Fcall.dll" (r1 As Long, ByVal num As String)
```

Comment: Excel reports, "compile error, expected string constant" for ActiveWorkbook.Path ? Do you perhaps know what that means (I don't know VB much, so this may be something trivial ...)

Comment: It means that for a Declare statement, you need a constant string - and ActiveWorkbook.Path is a function call (or a property), so you can't use it.