# How to read output from Excel file into Fortran?

Tags: excel, fortran

I have an excel sheet with the following columns for a stock chart:

1. Open
2. High
3. Low
4. Close
5. Day Average

How do i use Fortran to pull only the "Day Average" from the excel file?

I am new to Fortran and haven't been able to find anything that could help except for the link below but its pretty difficult for me to grasp since i am looking for something different than what the link is showing me:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_simple_input_and_output

Comment: Save your data from excel as csv file (comma or any other symbol separated) and read it with fortran

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, contrary to the other answers CSV is not the easiest file to read. Go to File/Save as/Other Formats and save it as *Formatted text (space delimited)*. Depending on your locale, you will either have a comma or a full stop as a decimal point, so you'll have to (either use an external editor to do a simple search/replace) or write a fortran subroutine that goes character by character, and replaces every comma with a full stop.

After that it's easy, no `;`'s to parse, so you just

```
program FreeFormat

real(4), dimension(5) :: open, high, low, close, dayaverage
real(4) :: average

open(unit=1, file='filename.prn', status='old')
do i=1,5
    read(1,*)open(i), high(i), low(i), close(i), dayaverage(i)
enddo
average = sum(dayaverage)/5
write(*,'("Average is",f5.2)')average

end program FreeFormat
```

You get the point ...

---

Here are a few links to get you started (Excel/Fortran DLL related) ...

[Trouble with file location in excel/fortran dll connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970404/trouble-with-file-location-in-excel-fortran-dll-connection)
[Fortran DLL & MS Excel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=39364)

Comment: Somewhere in the latest Fortran specification (possibly in the 2003 edition too) there is an explanation of how to make a processor use either , or . for the decimal separator, so the subroutine you suggest may be unnecessary.  I don't have the spec to hand so can't point directly to it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - You're right! Good call. I've heard of it before, but never used it, so usually don't think of it.

Comment: @AGilchrist - It is not complete, but just a template

Comment: Compiling and linking file: FreeFormat1.f95
D:\Program Files\Silverfrost\FreeFormat1.F95(5) : warning 868 - Opening unit 1 may affect the operation of input from the default unit '*' - are you sure you want to do this?
D:\Program Files\Silverfrost\FreeFormat1.F95(7) : error 304 - Non-writable expression in READ statement
D:\Program Files\Silverfrost\FreeFormat1.F95(7) : error 52 - Compilation abandoned
Compilation failed.

Comment: I have the excel file, I just need fortran to calculate the day average and than ask for the output through the excel since excel has the day average <---- (output)

Comment: @AGilchrist - What do you mean "ask for the output through the excel ...." ? Connecting the results of the program through the dll file and excel, is a whole different story alltogether.

Comment: Idigas I appreciate your help so far. Thanks a lot. But I am very bad in explaning. So let me rephrase. I have the excel with a date, open high low close and day average. Now I need fortran to calculate the average of open high low and close.  So just guide and help me on how to accomplish that with the codes?

Comment: @AGilchrist - (it's LDigas, but never mind that). I too am somewhat bad at explaining things unfortunatelly :) Calculating the average is not a problem, as a matter of fact, it can be done in excel with the AVERAGE function as well, without the need for fortran. Calculating the average of the above in fortran is just a matter of summing them up and dividing by 5 in this case. Writing it out is also not a problem. The problem is if you want to get that result back into excel "programmatically". It can be done with DLL-Excel connection, but that is a bit more complicated.

Comment: hmm i see. But can you tell me the code you mentioned earlier on how to write it? So that I can have fortran tell me the average from excel directly?

Comment: @AGilchrist - For how to connect DLL with Excel (depends on your excel version, your fortran compiler, there are also some path issues in there as well) check out the older questions on that matter. One of them is even mine I recall. It should answer some of your questions. For how to print average from fortran see above. But really, if all you wish to do is to calculate the average just use the AVERAGE function, or calculate it manually - this is a waste of time if that is the only reason for you wanting to do it.

Comment: Yes, somehow I have to do it via Fortran. I already have the average in excel. I just a line of program that can actually read the average directly from excel. I have Office 2010.

Comment: @AGilchrist - See some of the links. Also, it depends on your compiler as well.

Comment: @AGilchrist if you are constrained to reading a .xls file directly from Fortran, and cannot use a .csv version of the data (saved from Excel), this problem becomes a _lot_ harder.

Answer (score 2):

The native binary format of an Excel file will be very difficult to parse.   Export the file to text or CSV, as already suggested. CSV will probably be easiest.   You probably want to use "list directed IO", which has the source form:

```
read (unit-number, *) format-items
```

Fortran list-directed IO will read into the variables in the list "format-items" is a very flexible manner.  The items in the file should be separated by deliminators such as spaces or commas.  For your case, have five variables corresponding to the five columns in order to reach the 5th one that you want.   Fortran is record-oriented, so you do one read per line.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to read and parse the Excel file in Fortran to get the values you want. If you are new to the language then this might be very hard to do. Maybe it's easier to save the Excel sheet in a CSV format and parse that? Good luck!